# Connect to hadoop cluster with C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop

I am using the free distribution of the Apache Hadoop downloaded from Apache Foundation website. I am trying to connect to my Hadoop cluster through C#. I did not know what should I put in the password field since I do not have a password for Hadoop.

My code is:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;

try
{
   IHadoop hadoopClient = Hadoop.Connect(new Uri("http://192.168.0.90:50070"), "alex", password);
}
catch(Exception exException)
{
   MessageBox.Show(exException.Message);
}
```

Which password should I try?

Answer (score 0):

You can try set password to **null** with **hadoop** user as it is shown here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/data_otaku/2013/09/07/hadoop-for-net-developers-implementing-a-simple-mapreduce-job/.

Or you can use

```
var hadoopClient = Hadoop.Connect();
```

Comment: i have already tried to use null.But it didn't work.I asked to get the password information beacuse i want to access a remote hadoop cluster deployed in a distant machine , is there any possiblity to get the Hadoop cluster password .Thank you